# How to automate validation of console logs from adobe analytics using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, adobe-analytics, testautomationfx, browser-console

I am trying to validate the console has certain data which is being produced by adobe analytics.

Manually I have added debugger for adobe analytics plugin to my chrome browser and upon certain actions that I perform on UI (e.g. clicking on a button after providing data on some fields), I am validating the browser console log by going to developer tools and console.

I want to automate these whole steps using Selenium any leads would be greatly appreciated !!

I tried getting the logs directly and validate the data section but it's not working and is there any way using Selenium4 it can be done much easily?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question is way too broad. SO isn't really a multi-step "how to" / tutorial site; it's an answer-specific-question site. I suggest you start with the Selenium documentation / communities for code examples / tutorials.